# Bluemix - Server error, status code: 403, error code: forbidden, message: No such account

Tags: ibm-cloud

Logging to the Bluemix using cf cli gives this error. However, I can log-in with the same credentials using web.

Comment: Please let us know using a comment whether Crescenzo's answer addresses your issue. We want to know!

Answer (score 2):

Download latest version of cf here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

and login following these steps:

login to bluemix:

```
cf api https://api.[REGION].bluemix.net     [REGION is 'eu-gb', 'ng' or 'au-syd'. Depends where your app is staged ]

cf login  -u <your_email> -o <your_org> -s <yourspace>
```

take note that:

IF your dashboard UI link is: http://console.ng.bluemix.net and your organization is "myorg"(for example) [you can select your current organization clicking on your icon profile on right on top and select one in dropdown list ]

use these commands:

```
cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

IF your dashboard UI link is: http://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net and your organization is "myorg"(for example) [you can select your current organization clicking on your icon profile on right on top and select one in dropdown list ]

use these commands:

```
cf api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

the same for au-syd region (IF your dashboard UI link is: http://console.au-syd.bluemix.net)

```
cf api https://api.au-syd.bluemix.net
cf login -u bluemix_id -o myorg
```

you can know which region, org and space is currently set typing:

```
cf target
```

Comment: Hello, thx for the hint, didn't work out though. Installed version 1.16.1. Can only log-in through the BlueMix Portal.

Comment: are you able to login using another machine ? It could be an issue with firewall or something like that.

Comment: No, I'am not. However, I've created a new demo account and it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

if you've this kind of error

[image]

follow this steps :

first :

```
cf login  -o org_name -s space_name -sso
```

after this, you can get your One time passcode in this url :

https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/showpasscode.jsp